# Is it possible to style a JavaScript-generated HTML element with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, date

I have this:

```
var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var d=new Date();
var month=new Array(12);
month[0]="January";
month[1]="February";
month[2]="March";
month[3]="April";
month[4]="May";
month[5]="June";
month[6]="July";
month[7]="augustus";
month[8]="September";
month[9]="October";
month[10]="November";
month[11]="December";



var d = new Date();

document.write('<span class="date">' + weekday[d.getDay()] + " " + (d.getDate()) + " " + month[d.getMonth()] + '</span>');
```

How do I refer to the code in HTML so I can style it with CSS?

Comment: How are you attempting to style the elements? It seems you're creating a span with the date details as inner HTML.

Comment: What a weird question title. Can one be so free to invent a more smart title?

Comment: You're not styling JavaScript, you're styling an HTML element that was dynamically created *using* JavaScript.

Comment: Hi to all, That is not my original title, someone else edited my title and I excepted because I thought it might be important to him/her

Comment: @Tejs I updated the code using the answer provided, the html is `<span class="date"></span>`

Comment: @AlienWebguy's answer below is correct. What is not working about his answer?

Comment: @Stephen P Thanks, I have learned something once again:)

Comment: @Tejs Well..I don't see anything on my page, no date

Comment: One who edited it did not change the title's meaning. He just rewrote the title using proper English. I've fixed the title's meaning (and other minor things in the question). Are you Dutch or something? ;)

Comment: I don't remember the original title but I think I abbreviated the title because I assumed that everyone else here would know what I was talking about. So the original question emphasized on "**how** to style(the date)" while the current title emphasizes on "is this possible". Very different I would think. Yes I'm Dutch, good guess:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.write('<span class="date">' + weekday[d.getDay()] + " " + (d.getDate()) + " " + month[d.getMonth()] + '</span>');
```

**CSS**:

```css
.date {
    color:blue;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/teLca/

Comment: It doesn't work on my page. Please have a look at the updated question. Maybe there is something wrong with the rest of the code

Comment: @Youss make sure you're loading your javascript before your CSS.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Hi, I accept your answer because obviously it is good. It still doesn't work for me but that (I think) has something to do with the rest of my page. It's a big complex page. I might be simply blocking the date with some div or something like that. I will look in to it. Thanks for the code:)

Comment: I think you're just loading your CSS before your JS is outputting so it's trying to style something that's not there yet.

Comment: @AlienWebguy I think we where both right. It works, I can see the date when reloading my page but then it is getting overlapped by some div. But as far as I can see it doesn't have any style to it. I tried positioning and everything else, it wont move from the top left of the page.. I'm going to look at it tomorrow, I'm sure I can fix it now, thanks again